# How to hide div with @media in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i have the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.3em;
}

.a1 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background-color: #B8336A;
}

.a2 {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  background-color: #726DA8;
}

.a3 {
  background-color: #7C8CC4;
}

.a4 {
  background-color: #9FD2DB;
}

.a5 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  background-color: #C490D2;
}

.a6 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: #B8336A;
}

.a7 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  background-color: #726DA8;
}

.a8 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background-color: #726DA8;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .a8 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a1">1</div>
  <div class="a2">2</div>
  <div class="a3">3</div>
  <div class="a4">4</div>
  <div class="a5">5</div>
  <div class="a6">6</div>
  <div class="a7">7</div>
  <div class="a8">8</div>
</div>
```

I need to hide the div with class "a8" when the max-width is 1200px with using @media, i tried to use display: none, but it isn't work, i also tried visibility: hidden but it isn't what I need. What i should do? Thank you for help

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: display none isn't work

Comment: You did it correctly. It works. Not sure why you aren't seeing it.

Comment: Are you confusing `max-width` and `min-width`? Are you trying to hide the `div` once the screen is _greater_ than `1200px`?